# Dispatching a KeyEvent after the current event is finished?

Tags: android, android-edittext, keylistener, keyevent

I have an OnKeyListener(), living in a class that extends an EditText, that when the enter key is pressed checks for a certain character at the end of the line and if it exists dispatches another KeyEvent to send a tab press back to the EditText. But what is happening is it adds the tab and then creates a new line. I need the tab after the new line is created. Is there anything that gets triggered after the OnKeyListener()/OnKey() methods that I could put my "tab event"? Or another way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could append the linefeed and tab in your onKey method and then return true to indicate that the event has been consumed to prevent the original linefeed from being processed afterward.

```
public boolean onKey (final View view, final int i, final KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    Editable editableText = ((EditText)view).getText();

    if (shouldAppendTab(editableText)) {
        editableText.append('\n');
        editableText.append('\t');
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Replace **shouldAppendTab(editableText)** with your code for determining whether you want the tab to be appended.

Comment: OK i think this will work! but I dont want to append at the end of the edittext, but at the cursor (.getSelectionStart()). there is public void append (CharSequence text, int start, int end) but i'm guessing start and end are in the charsequence and not where in the edittext... No good documentation on that.

Comment: In that case use insert instead of append.

Comment: i just did getText().replace(getSelectionStart(), getSelectionEnd(), "\n\t"); insert sounds like it would work also. thanks! -edit ok switching to insert so i dont have to getSelectionEnd() ;)